# Delphi 7 - How to tell if object touches a color or another object

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, collision

I'm writing 2d mini-games for another program I'm working on.

Problem is that I have very limited knowledge on coding that works with colliding objects.

For Example: how to test if 2 spheres collide like in Agar.io
or how the blocks from tetris detect that they touch each other,
or how Snake detects that the snake bit itself/food (without looking if the epicenters/coordinates of the middle of the objects are equal).

I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: If you're looking to detect colors or lines in a graphic drawing, then you're doing it wrong. The display should only be a display - not a source of collision detection. That should instead be controlled with back-end objects or similar. The user view should be entirely independent of this structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collision testing is easy.
If you want to test if two circles collide check the distance between their two center points:

In a plane the distance between to points is calculated with the Pythagorean theorem sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2).

```
if (sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)) > (Radius(Circle1)+Radius(Circle2)) then 
//x1,y1 = center point of circle1
//x2,y2 = center point of circle2
//or more efficiently:
a:= (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2
b:= (Radius(Circle1)+Radius(Circle2))^2;
if a > b then
```

If you want to check if two boxes collide there's a standard RTL routine for that.

```
if IntersectRect(Rect1,Rect2) then ....
```

As far as the snake goes, the thing that you're describing:

> if the epicenters/coordinates of the middle of the objects are equal

Is exactly how it can be done, but a faster alternative is to use a discrete grid with integer coordinates and call a collision when two parts of the snake are on the same cell.

```
type
  // The grid is initially empty except for a border around the edges
  TBodyPart = (bpNone, bpBorder, bpTail, bpBody, bpHead);
  TSnakeGrid = array[0..20,0..20] of TBodyPart;

  TSnake = class(TObject)
  private
     SnakeLength: integer;
     Grid: TSnakeGrid;
     .... 
     function IsCollision: boolean;

 function TSnake.IsCollision: boolean;
 begin
   Result:= Grid[Head.x, Head,y] <> bpEmpty;
 end;

 procedure TSnake.MoveSnake(Direction: TDirection);
 begin
   //Move the head
   Grid[Head.x, Head.y]:= bpBody;
   Inc(SnakeLength);
   case Direction of
     north: Dec(Head.y);
     south:= Inc(Head.y);
     west:= Dec(Head.x);
     east: Inc(Head.x);
   end; {case}
   if Grid[Head.x, Head.y] <> bpEmpty then Grid[Head.x,Head,y]:= bpHead
   else GameOver;
 end;
```

Google for "collision detection delphi vcl" and you will find lots of code.

Comment: It is more efficient to square both sides of the inequality and thereby avoid the sqrt

Comment: Snake operates on a discrete grid with integer coords. Collision occurs if the snake's head enters a point which already contains something. No algo required really.

Comment: Thanks David, incorporated those two changes.

Answer (score 1):

A classic Snake and Tetris games usually works on a grid, so a 2D array can hold all elements. For collisions you can then simply look-up if there are objects in the 2D array at a given grid position.

For detecting sphere overlap, you need some geometry to determine if the distance between the centers of the spheres is smaller than both radius combined, see [more on the theory here](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php)

```
sphere1x = 100;
sphere1y = 200;
sphere1r = 5;

sphere2x = 105;
sphere2y = 200;
sphere2r = 10;

deltax = sphere1x - sphere2x;
deltay = sphere1y - sphere2y;
dist = (deltax * deltax) + (deltay * deltay);
rad2 = (sphere1r * sphere1r) + (sphere2r * sphere2r);

// for the actual distance you'd have to square root both dist and rad2, 
// but we just want to compare which is bigger, so this is skipped for optimisation

if (dist < rad2) then
begin
    // sphere collision
end;
```

Comment: Okay I have edited my non-answer to a (hopefully) more helpful one